# PHP get string by string

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have the following code

```
json_decode( $images_json );
json_decode( $cites_json );
```

But instead I want to use the input by a dynamic string, like this...

```
json_decode( {{$name}}_json );
```

...where `$name` is a string containing "`images`" or "`cites`".

Is it possible? How?

Comment: [Variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
json_decode( ${$name.'_json'} );
```

But variable variables is not good idea usually, you may use an array to refactor your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use this;

```
json_decode( ${$name . '_json'} );
```

You can refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for further detail